# SDL2 Exporting to linux

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++, sdl, gnu

I wrote my application on MSVC using SDL2,
while exporting it to linux, I faced a lot of problems.I solved most them except This one [image]

I don't know what to do ? anyone have an idea about whats going on ?
The compiler is GCC using C++14 standards.

The surface is defined as:

```
SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font->getFont(), p_Text.c_str(), { p_Color.r,p_Color.g, p_Color.b, p_Color.a }); 
m_Texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ENGINE->getRenderer(), textSurface);
```

Comment: This question would be more-searchable if this error-text was pasted as text.

Comment: Didnt find anything actually

Comment: What is that `font->getFont()` returning?  Is it doing something wacky because the font does not exist on Linux or suchlike? Are you calling `TTF_Init()` ?

Comment: a non null ptr, Yes im calling TTF_Init() its same code it was working fine on Windows and still working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved the problem i was installing wrong SDL2 libraries:
used these:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-dev
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-image-dev
sudo apt-get install libsdl2-ttf-dev
```

Comment: Ah, that's a good issue fixed.  It's hard debugging these sorts of problems.

Answer (score 1):

`Segmentation fault` means you're trying to read (or write) memory you do not own.  So one of the pointers in that piece of code:

```
surface->map->info.r
```

is bad.

Check you have allocated the space for the `surface` and `map` data structures correctly, also that their space has not been de-allocated before use.  Failing that, the pointers themselves may have become corrupt.

There's a great memory debugging tool named `valgrind` on Linux.  Run that with your program, and update your question with the output.

Comment: That peace of code doesn't even belong to my code its SDL2 internals i think

Comment: @Omarito - Yes it is part of SDL2, but something is breaking that structure.  It could just be a write past the end of a buffer or whatever.  Your code "owns" the surface right?

Comment: The surface is a text

Comment: `SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font->getFont(), p_Text.c_str(), { p_Color.r,p_Color.g, p_Color.b, p_Color.a });
 m_Texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ENGINE->getRenderer(), textSurface);`